# Access to heroku toolbelt commands in a scheduled heroku dyno?

Tags: heroku

I want to call heroku postgres backup/restore commands within a scheduled heroku task, but the heroku toolbelt isn't available from bash prompt, so I can't call heroku commands:

```
$ heroku run bash --app myapp
Running `bash` attached to terminal... up, run.4805
~ $ heroku --version
bash: heroku: command not found
```

How can I get heroku commands available in my scheduled bash script?
I don't know anything about Ruby or Ruby Gems.

Answer (score 8):

None of the other solutions worked for me since Heroku locks the filesystem after the buildpacks finish running.

There's a third-party buildpack that installs the CLI for you. First you set your auth key as an ENV variable on your app:

```
heroku config:set HEROKU_API_KEY=`heroku auth:token` -a myapp
```

Then add the buildpack:

`heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-cli -a myapp`

Redeploy your app and it should be able to access your apps via the CLI. If you have https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata enabled, you can even access your current app's name with $HEROKU_APP_NAME.

Comment: This is the best answer as of today. Thanks Dylan!

Comment: @DylanReile Can you please show how you **set an auth key as an ENV variable** ?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen Do you have https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli installed locally? If so, `heroku auth:token` will output your token. You can then set it on your app like: `heroku config:set HEROKU_API_KEY=your_token_goes_here -a your-app`

Answer (score 6):

Put this at the top of your scheduled bash script:

```
# install heroku toolbelt
# inspired by https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install.sh
curl -s https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.heroku.com/heroku-client/heroku-client.tgz | tar xz
mv heroku-client/* .
rmdir heroku-client
PATH="bin:$PATH"
```

then, for example, you can call:

```
heroku pg:reset HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YELLOW_URL  --app myapp-staging --confirm myapp-staging
heroku pgbackups:restore HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_YELLOW_URL `heroku pgbackups:url --app myapp-production` --app myapp-staging --confirm myapp-staging
```

and poof!  Staging database is updated from production database.

Comment: how do you handle heroku cli asking for credentials?

Answer (score 4):

As Heather Piwowar said, you can indeed download and untar the heroku tollbelt yourself, but no need to move files around after this. Here is a shorter version:

```
curl -s https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.heroku.com/heroku-client/heroku-client.tgz | tar xz
PATH="/app/heroku-client/bin:$PATH"
```

You can now use the `heroku` command as you wish.

For authentification, you may want to set the `HEROKU_API_KEY` env var (using `heroku config:set HEROKU_API_KEY=1234567890 -a your-app-name`).

Also, note that the first use of the `heroku` command will run longer than expected because it will try to install the latest version, dependencies and core plugins.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Heroku Scheduler](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler) and configure the following command (as an example) to create a database backup:

```
curl -s https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.heroku.com/heroku-client/heroku-client.tgz \
 | tar xz && ./heroku-client/bin/heroku pg:backups:capture -a you-app-name-here
```

For this to work, you need to add a Config Variable named `HEROKU_API_KEY` and set its value to the "API Key" value from your Accounts page.