# What is the heroku scheduler command to run a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, heroku, heroku-cli

I trying to run `myFile` using the heroku plugin "scheduler".

Simplified file structure (MyProject is the root)

```
MyProject -> bin -> myFile
```

MyFile

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const foo = require('myFunc');
foo();
process.exit();
```

Testing MyFile from the heroku-cli bash locally from my pc, it works as expected. However I the heroku scheduler cmd is most likely wrong, because as the scheduler triggers at the specfied time I get the following error in the log:

```
2018-09-05T12:00:08.323971+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `run eovendoEarnMoney` by user scheduler@addons.heroku.com
2018-09-05T12:01:05.759152+00:00 heroku[scheduler.4007]: Starting process with command `run myFile`
2018-09-05T12:01:06.419284+00:00 heroku[scheduler.4007]: State changed from starting to up
2018-09-05T12:01:08.283555+00:00 heroku[scheduler.4007]: State changed from up to complete
2018-09-05T12:01:08.223306+00:00 heroku[scheduler.4007]: Process exited with status 127
2018-09-05T12:01:08.154580+00:00 app[scheduler.4007]: bash: heroku: command not found
```

[image]

I tried changing the bash command (in the picture above) to: `run myFile`. Resulting in the same error with the exception that the error this time was:

```
2018-09-05T12:01:08.154580+00:00 app[scheduler.4007]: bash: run: command not found
```

I have added a buildpack for heroku-cli following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45043155/10238810) as I thought it would help.

**What is the correct command to run "myFile"?**

*There is no documentation on this matter*

Answer (score 0):

According to [Heroku Scheduler Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) you should use `heroku run myFile` to test the command is functioning locally. 
The documentation also explains the way to do it with rails from the Scheduler Dashboard:

> For example, add `rake update_feed`, select “Hourly” and “:30” to update feeds every hour on the half-hour. Then add rake send_reminders, select “Daily” and “00:00” to send reminders every day at midnight.

So in your case you should change `heroku run myFile` to `myFile` on to the Scheduler Dashboard